# ManyToManyField working on shell but not on server

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

This is the rarer behavior I've ever seen. I've got two ManyToMany relationships on a table:

```
# models.py

...

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=128)
    ...

class Report(models.Model):
    ...
    companies = models.ManyToManyField(Company)
    customers = models.ManyToManyField(Customer)
    ...
```

The form is a normal form with no custom `save()`.

When I create a Report object through my webapp I can successfully query them on shell:

```
In [3]: report.customers.all()
Out[3]: <QuerySet [<Customer: xxxxxxx>]>
```

But on server (I use gunicorn), no `customers` appears on the browser (through a regular `ReportList` based on `generic.ListView`) or in the server log when I query them, but `companies` field returns correct results on query.

```
# views.py
from core import models

class ReportList(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    permission_required = 'core.add_report'
    model = models.Report
```

Here the template...

```
# report_list.html

{% for object in object_list %}
<td>
    {% for customer in object.customers.all %}
    <span class="label label-success">{{ customer.name }}</span>&nbsp;
    {% endfor %} <-- This doen't work -->
</td>
<td>
    {% for company in object.companies.all %}
    <span class="label label-success">{{ company.name }}</span>&nbsp;
    {% endfor %} <-- This works  :-O -->
</td>
{% endfor %}
```

It looks to me at first that it could be some kind of conflict with another table or field, but I review all the possibilities and nothing apparently is wrong.

Comment: can you share your view code?

Comment: I've just added the ListView code to the question. As you can see, is a regular ListView

Comment: Please show us the `Customer` model - specifically how the `name` field is defined.

Comment: @solarissmoke I've just edited the question so you can see the `Customer` model.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, It was a conflict with another table in another app. In the first app I had:

```
# app1 models.py
...

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=128)
    ...

class Report(models.Model):
    ...
    companies = models.ManyToManyField(Company)
    customers = models.ManyToManyField(Customer)
    ...
```

And in other app I had:

```
# app2 models.py
...

from app1.models import Customer

class Report(models.Model):
    ...
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    ...
```

I did only need to add an specific `related_name` in the app2 foreign key. Always recommended to add this unique `related_name` to avoid this kind of problems :-S